# How to create a React Native code to upload image using this fastapi code

Tags: react-native, axios, fastapi, multipartform-data, image-upload

```
from fastapi import     FastAPI, UploadFile, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
import os
import base64
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()

# Set up CORS
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Update with your React app's URL
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

class Item(BaseModel):
    category: str
     images: List[UploadFile]

     @validator("images")
    def validate_images(cls, value):
        allowed_formats = ['jpeg', 'png', 'gif']
        allowed_size_mb = 5  # Adjust as needed

         for image in value:
            if image.content_type.lower() not in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']:
                raise     ValueError(f"Unsupported image format. Supported formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF")

            if image.file:
                file_size_mb = len(image.file.read()) / (1024 * 1024)
               image.file.seek(0)  # Reset     file pointer

                if file_size_mb > allowed_size_mb:
                raise     ValueError(f"Image size exceeds the allowed limit of {allowed_size_mb} MB")

         return value

def   save_uploaded_images(category: str, images: List[UploadFile]):
upload_directory = f"uploaded_images/{category}"
    os.makedirs(upload_directory, exist_ok=True)

    saved_image_paths = []

     for image in images:
        file_path = os.path.join(upload_directory, image.filename)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
           file.write(image.file.read())
            saved_image_paths.append(file_path)

    return saved_image_paths

def get_images_by_category(category: str):
image_directory = f"uploaded_images/{category}"

    images = []

    for file_name in os.listdir(image_directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(image_directory, file_name)
        with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
            image_data = base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode("utf-8")
             images.append({"name": file_name, "data": image_data})

     return images

@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
 async def  create_upload_files(item: Item = Depends()):
    category = item.category

    try:
        saved_image_paths = save_uploaded_images(category, item.images)
        confirmation_messages = [f"Image '{os.path.basename(path)}' uploaded to '{category}' category." for path in saved_image_paths]

        return JSONResponse(content={"confirmation_messages": confirmation_messages}, status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

@app.get("/get_images/{category}")
async def get_images(category: str):
    try:
        images = get_images_by_category(category)
        return {"category": category, "images": images}
    except Exception as e:
    raise  HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
```

My main issue is I am getting an axios network error when trying to call backend from frontend. I then got a 422 error. I want to upload image locally using the selected category as subfolder in uploaded_images folder

How do I pass the formdata to frontend?

I tried using fetch and am getting 422 error so I assume it's how I'm passing the data that is the issue. Please guide me how to pass it. Will provide additional information if required